# How to execute multiple queries in sqlapi++ with oracle

Tags: c++, oracle, sqlapi++

When I give single query it is working, but when I give multiple queries I am getting invalid character error .

Single Query:

```
 cmd.setCommandText("create table sample (num number(19,0))");
 cmd.Execute();
```

Multiple Queries:

```
 cmd.setCommandText("create table sample (num number(19,0)); create index test on sample(num ASC);");
 cmd.Execute();
```

I have used lot of separators such as ; , / etc, between each queries , but none of them wowrked .

Comment: I don't think you can execute several queries at once this way. You have to submit each of them one by one.

Comment: That is possible in sqlapi++ with sql server , thats why I asked for oracle .

Answer (score 0):

At last I had to settle with opting for PL/SQL statements  . The code below is what I used .  I would be happy to know , if there is any other way of doing

```
cmd.setCommandText(" BEGIN \
                       execute immediate 'create table sample (num number(19,0))'; \
                       execute immediate 'create index test on sample(num ASC)';  \
                     END ");
cmd.Execute();
```